# Any performance difference between data from function arguments vs assigned variable?

Tags: javascript, performance, architecture

This might sound like a noob question but here goes;
Basically, I'm passing a large amount of data from one object to another. Below is a simplified example.

```
// Example 1
function Person(hugeData) {
    this.info = function() {
        console.log(hugeData);
    }
}
Homer = new Person(hugeData);
Homer.info();
```

Compared with

```
// Example 2
function Person() {
    var hugeData;

    this.set = function(data) {
        hugeData = data;
    }

    this.info = function() {
        console.log(hugeData);
    }
}
Homer = new Person();
Homer.set(hugeData);
Homer.info();
```

Is there much of a difference performance-wise between the two code snippets? Please focus on the context of the example rather than the code itself (setting object variable vs passing by arguments).

While the example above is for Javascript, I would also like to know if the same principle applies for other programming languages like PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: Performance questions should be supported by the results of your own research and tests. Did you try to time both in 1M iterations loop? What was **your** result? Then we can try to run the same code (it has to be runnable **as is**) and compare and discuss our results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not at all.

Without going into much detail now, both, *formal paramters* and *local variables* are stored within the such called *Activation Object* (in ES3) or the *Lexical Environment Record* (ES5) under the hood.

So access times should be identical by spec.

---

If you want to know the details, checkout:

http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/

and

http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-2-lexical-environments-ecmascript-implementation/

---

Testcase: http://jsperf.com/formal-parameters-vs-local-variables-access-time

Answer (score 2):

I assume the major point of your question is whether this line...

`hugeData = data;`

... in your code may affect the performance.

And the answer is no, it's not (at least not so it can affect the application's performance).

If `hugeData` refers to an object (and remember arrays in JS are essentially objects), it actually stores only a reference to this object. And the reference is what will be copied, without any duplication of the object's contents.

If `hugeData` refers to a string, it *can* be a bit more complicated... but as far as I know, most modern browsers (check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_internal_string_guide), as example) now implement 'copy-on-writing' technique. In other words, the string won't be duplicated here as well.

Comment: You're right. It is an object; a view model object to be specific

Answer (score 0):

Passing by variable is the best thing. Because it's obvious your huge data is not a primitive so you are going to only refer that in the functions context.
Look at jAndy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to generalize in this case because every implementation of Javascript is different.

I could imagine that when you pass a big hunk of data with the creation of an object, you are saving a reallocation of memory, which would happen when you create the object with few data first and then add a lot of data to it later. But most JS implementation will store the big data chunk in a reference anyway, so it is unlikely that it really matters.